# "Edit Style" option not available in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I'm currently reading the third edition of Head First C# to start my C# related study. I'm currently making the "Save the Humans" game and the book is asking me to right-click on a textbox and click "Edit Style" and then on "Apply Resource" to select SubheaderTextBlockStyle to make the text bigger. However, I can't find the "Edit Style" menu button so I'm kind of stuck on this very small issue right now. Can someone enlighten for me?

I'm running Visual Studio 2012 (since this is the most recent version the book describes, even though I also have the 2015-edition installed) on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you sure you create the same type of application? Winforms or WPF or ASP..??? SubheaderTextBlockStyle is part of XAML markup.

Comment: I'm at Visual C# > Store Apps > Blank App (Windows)

Answer (score 0):

You have added a [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but should have added a [TextBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.textblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

TextBlock:

> Provides a lightweight control for displaying small amounts of flow
>   content.

TextBox:

> Represents a control that can be used to display or edit unformatted
>   text.